# resolve pipenv install weasyprint error in Docker

Tags: django, docker, alpine-linux

I'm using Alpine linux for my Docker setup. 
Here is the Dockerfile.

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk --update --upgrade --no-cache add cairo-dev pango-dev gdk-pixbuf


RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev libffi-dev\
    && apk add postgresql \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg \
    && pip install Pillow \
    && apk del build-deps

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY ./Pipfile /usr/src/app/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

which results in stalling on the installation of cairocffi and giving the error of

unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) is gonna save your life, no matter if you're using pipenv or not,

For Alpine(>=3.6), use

```
apk --update --upgrade add gcc musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev libffi-dev cairo-dev pango-dev gdk-pixbuf-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had figured it out, and ended up using the libraries you've noted above.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-WHI4rf2VE) link however, which recommends adding the line:

```
RUN apk add --update python python-dev py-pip build-base
```

to the build file and works.